# SQL select rows but remove records with duplicated phone number

Tags: sql

I've got an Application table containing phone numbers.  I'm trying to select the top 10000 rows ordered by the ApplicationId descending (to get the latest apps) but I want to remove all the duplicate phone numbers.

I've tried..

```
select distinct * from
(select top 10000 Forenames, PhoneNumber
from Application
order by ApplicationId desc) AS Applications
```

Although this query sorts it by Forename ascending, ie no longer in ApplicationId order.

Comment: try using group by phonenumber

Comment: But then I can't order by applicationid as it's not in the group by clause

Comment: So for `PhoneNumber` which have multiple `ApplicationId` which one to use for ordering?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @MartinSmith you can use group by then order by but in your problem it won't help you. Sorry for my previous commend.

Comment: SQL Server, Gordon Linoffs answer below appears to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:  Get the latest application id for each phone number and then return the information about those.

```
select a.*
from (select limit 10000 PhoneNumber, max(ApplicationId) as maxaid
      from Application a
      group by PhoneNumber
      order by max(aid) desc
     ) list join
     Application a
     on a.ApplicationId = list.maxaid
order by ApplicationId desc;
```

Comment: That's worked perfectly thanks, didn't realise the max() function could be used this way

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (select top 10000 Forenames, PhoneNumber, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PhoneNumber ORDER BY Forenames DESC) AS Row
from Application
order by ApplicationId desc) as temp
Where Row = 1
```